# Placing images in LWC using slds

Tags: lightning-web-components, slds, slds-grid, sfdc-styleguide

I have been trying to work on some images to be placed in a particular pattern. The images appears to indicate about the record. **If the record's field abc = true then I display images 1-8 below**. If a particular image isn't present the area shouldn't be blank but dynamic. Following is what I tried for the below pattern:

[image: Image pattern]

1 and 2 is fixed, while 3-8 needs to placed in the above manner. For eg. if 5 and 6 isn't present, the rest should adjust and take it position.

Here's the code:

```
   <template >
      <lightning-card title="myimages" icon-name="utility:warning">
         <div class="my-container">    <!--1 st row-->        

               <div class="my_slds-col">                    
                    <template if:true={1}>
                        <div class="slds-text-title slds-align_absolute-center">1</div>
                        <span><img src={1} title="1" height="90%" width="90%"></span>
                    </template>  
                                 
            </div>
            <div class="my_slds-col">                    
                <template if:true={2}>
                    <div class="slds-text-title slds-align_absolute-center">2</div>
                    <span><img src={2} title="2" height="90%" width="90%"></span>
                </template>  
                 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="my-container">   <!--2nd row-->  
                <div class="my_slds-col">                            
                    <template if:true={3}> <!--CHANGE-->
                        <div class="slds-text-title slds-align_absolute-center">3</div>
                        <span><img src={3} height="100%"></span>   
                    </template>                 
                </div>
            
                <div class="my_slds-col">                    
                    <template if:true={4}>
                        <div class="slds-text-title slds-align_absolute-center">4</div>
                        <span><img src={4} height="100%"></span>
                    </template>
                </div>
                <div class="my_slds-col">
                    
                    <template if:true={5}>
                        <div class="slds-text-title slds-align_absolute-center">5</div>
                        <span><img src={5} height="100%"></span>
                    </template>
                </div>
        </div> 
       <div class="my-container"> <!--3rd row-->  
            <div class="my_slds-col">                    
                <template if:true={6}> 
                    <div class="slds-text-title slds-align_absolute-center">6</div>
                        <span><img src={6} height="65%" width="65%"></span>
                    </template>
            </div>
            <div class="my_slds-col">
                
                <template if:true={7}>
                    <div class="slds-text-title slds-align_absolute-center">7</div>
                    <span><img src={7} height="100%"></span>
                </template>
            </div> 
            <div class="my_slds-col">                 
                <template if:true={8}> <!--CHANGE-->
                    <div class="slds-text-title slds-align_absolute-center">8</div>
                    <span><img src={8} height="100%"></span>
                </template>
            </div> 
        </div>
  </lightning-card>
```

I divided into 3 rows and arranged them in columns. Kindly ignore the if conditions.

css:

```
.insp-container{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
     font-weight: bold;
 }
```

**Problem Statement:**

- I'm able to display as per above pattern but 3-8 are not static in my output. If 6 image is absent, 7 and 8 will not overlap perfectly but only adjust to the row.
- Is this the correct way considering the image sizes are consistent?

Is there any slds attribute that I show try to make the images 3-8 dynamic or any other method?

Apologies for the long question

Comment: Sorry, do you want to make images from 3 to 8 be of equal size and if one of them is empty, other images don't have to change their size or position?

Comment: other images will take it position. I was able to achieve this using <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters slds-wrap slds-p-vertical_medium">    let me put this in answer